# Add In для MS Office Excel

Tags: c#

Порекомендуйте "нестандартные" инструменты (не шаблон MS Visual Studio) для создания надстроек (AddIn) MS Office. Инфу в сети читал, но хотелось бы узнать ваш опыт.

P.S. Меткой поставил C#, но пойдет и C++. Delphi тоже будет нормальный. Офис 2003, 2007. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: А стандартный инструмент чем не устраивает?

Comment: Извиняюсь за поздний ответ. Стандартные инструменты устраивают, но я в своем вопросе интересовался готовыми классами-модулями-интерфейсами, где, как Вы понимаете, не требуется монотонной работы по "вбиванию" кода. Но, судя по всему, придется потратить время (надеюсь на улице будет мерзкая погода, что-бы оправдаться за нахождение дома :) ).